# Scheduled event based on database data

Tags: node.js

So I am storing some alerts in a database with a date that looks like -> 2011-05-26T07:56:00. Is there a way that I can run some event at the time saved in the database?

I'm using Postgre if it makes any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) package does the job for you. This offers a cron-like and not-cron-like job scheduler for Node.js. It also permits you to schedule jobs for execution at specific dates, with optional recurrence rules. It only uses a single timer at any given time.

Considering your case, you can make use of the **Date-based Scheduling** which is offered by the node-schedule module.

For eg, If you want a function to execute at 5:30am on December 21, 2012. (Remember - in JavaScript - 0 - January, 11 - December.)

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var date = new Date(2012, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
  console.log('Task being executed.');
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What happens if the server is restarted or down at the time of the scheduled event? Does it automatically retry/reschedule?

Comment: @FlorianWalther Will [this](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/issues/500) help?

Comment: This helps, thank you. So they don't survive a server restart. I guess one way to handle this is to store all the dates in a database and reschedule everything when the server starts up.

Comment: @FlorianWalther Yes. Exatly.