# How to facilitate temporal event based on the data from SQL database for the website?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web-deployment, cron-task

I'm creating a website that notifies (by sending mail) the user at some particular time (Time stored in MySQL database in the server i.e., local server). I'm not allowed to use Node.js for the backend, only PHP. First I thought of setting up a cron job but that seems unnecessary for this case. Is there any other way to facilitate this temporal event response based on the database data?

Comment: PHP runs either as part of a request from a client (browser) or in the command line (started by cron for example).  Which do you need?

Comment: If you are not allowed node are you allowed any webserver

Comment: A cron job is probably the best way to do this. Why do you think "it seems unnecessary"?

Comment: The time that the message or notification has to be sent is in the database, therefore the client wouldn't be requesting the PHP to run in the server. It has to be done with the cron-job-like method. Since this can be done in Node.js without a cron task in the command line, I was hoping to do the same with PHP.  [Node.js Schedule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834528/scheduled-event-based-on-database-data). If it's not possible then I would have to go with cron job. @SergiuParaschiv

Comment: `node-schedule` is essentially a CRON daemon written in JavaScript - it contains a queue/calendar with the scheduled jobs and periodically wakes up from idle/sleep state to check whether the current date/time matches any item(s) in the queue and if yes - it runs those jobs and removes them from the queue and then again goes to sleep for a while. Nothing complex here - just a different implementation of the same old tool.